# iCarousel swift set view attribute

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I want to set the attributes for icarousel in order to get this shape
[image]

I have this code to set it but the result not 100% right

```
  CGFloat count = [self circularCarouselItemCount];
        CGFloat spacing = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:2.5];
        CGFloat arc = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionArc withDefault:M_PI * 1.0];
        CGFloat radius = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:MAX(_itemWidth * spacing / 2.0, _itemWidth * spacing / 2.0 / tanf(arc/2.0/count))];
        CGFloat angle = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionAngle withDefault:offset / count * arc];
```

the result looks like

[image]

And if I change device size I get only 1 image.
How can I modify the attributes to get it in all screen sizes?